# Background color not showing behind text css

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with this assignment, I tried to add a background color to only the header but it doesn't show up behind the text here is  the css:

```
*{
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: aliceblue;
    background-color: #2a292b;
}
header{background-color: #3d3747;}
h1{font-size: 50px;text-align: center}
h2{font-size: 40px;text-align: center}
h3{font-size: 30px;text-align: center}
p{font-size: 20px;text-align: center; line-height: 1.5;}
```

and here is the html:

```
<body>
    <header >
        <h1>Youssef Sfexi</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <hr>
    </header>
    <section>
        <p> paragraph </p>
    </section>
</body>
```

here's the output i got:

I tried to add a background color to only the header but it doesn't show up behind the text

Comment: The universal selector `*` makes that all elements (including h1,h2 ..) get the defined background-color. Remove the universal assignment and the header gets the defined background-color for your header element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you're using `*` selector and setting the background color there. This rule will set all elements' background color to `#2a292b`, including all `<header>`'s children.

Alternatively, try to set the base rules to `body`:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: aliceblue;
    background-color: #2a292b;
}
```

Comment: I wonder where your answer has more helpful information than the comment I posted before. Such ultra-basic questions deserve no real answer in my opinion because the are answered already hundreds of of time bevor. Not to mention that the question itself is no helpful question for the community but more like a please-help-me question ...